# The term 'ConvertTo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet while executing Powershell script using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, powerbi

I was trying to execute powershell script from WinForms application using C# code.The code Trying to convert password to secure string. Also creating a PsCredential object.below is the code.

```
   Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();         
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Powershell.exe - Command Import - Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility");
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Powershell.exe - Command Import - Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'");
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$username = \"admin@ABCR.com\"");
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$password =\"#pas*1834&\"");
            Command convertTo = new Command("ConvertTo");
            convertTo.Parameters.Add("SecureString");
            convertTo.Parameters.Add("AsPlainText");
            convertTo.Parameters.Add("Force");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(convertTo);
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Cred = New - Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username,$password)");
            Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Getting an error from pipeline.Invoke() ***The term 'ConvertTo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet***.
If we comment this code getting another error ***The term 'New' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet***

The same powershell script execute from Windows powershell ISE without any issues.Any way to resolve this issue.Did I miss any thing

Comment: The cmdlet is called `ConvertTo-SecureString`.. `SecureString` is not a parameter, but part of the cmdlet's name

Comment: @Theo Thank you very much for quick reply. I am getting same error when change the code with addscript `pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$password =$password | ConvertTo - SecureString - AsPlainText - Force")`

Comment: @Theo I got your point.Let me try to rectify the command error

Comment: Don't put all those spaces in between where they do not belong. Try googling the command, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I understand your point.The issue I mentioned in question is resolved.But now getting another error **Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'Force** . My changed code is 
`pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$password=$pass | ConvertTo-SecureString - AsPlainText - Force");`

Comment: If you understood his point you would remove the erroneous spaces :-)

Comment: Please if you want to use PowerShell cmdlets, at least use your browser and find these cmdlets so you know how they are called and how to add parameters. Don't add spaces wherever you think they look nice around dashes. Spaces and dashes are part of PowerShell syntax and should be used the way they are meant to.